# Developed a framework, Cannot load underlying module for 'x'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-frameworks

First I have did tons of researches on this issue. Non of existing solution similar to my issue.

I developed a framework. It is a pretty heavy framework which include a c++ static library and contains both objective-c and swift codes. I have created a sample app that imports my framework to mimic the behaviour of people can using my framework.

I put the framework under a libs folder of the project. I have make sure the framework is under `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked frameworks and Libraries`. I have also make sure that the path to libs folder exists under `Framework Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths` and `User Header Search Paths`.

---

**Now** When I run the sample app using my actual device and running on the computer that contain my framework project file, it works perfectly.

**However** If I run the sample app using simulator devices, it told me `No such module x`

**Moreover** If I run the sample app using my actual device and running another computer that I didn't use to develop my framework project, it shows error `Cannot load underlying module for x`.

---

Has anyone had this problem before? Any hint would be appreciated.

(I have also tried clean, clean build folder, clean `Derived Data`, restart Xcode, restart computer etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by setting `Defines Module` to `No`
[image]